# How eureka provider carry custom metadata to eureka center

Tags: metadata, netflix-eureka

I use springcloud with eureka. now I want to get more information from the center about provider, so How eureka provider carry custom metadata to eureka center? the information shouldn't in the application.properties but generates by the provider.

Comment: So what have you tried so far? May you display your code please?

Answer (score 0):

In springcloud, we can override the default bean which named EurekaInstanceConfigBean by this:

```
@Bean
public EurekaInstanceConfigBean eurekaInstanceConfig()
```

in this method, you can fill the metadata as you lik.
it provide springcloud a custom config bean.

reference:http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/single/spring-cloud-netflix.html#_using_eureka_on_aws